# html table creates two rows all equal size and ignores height attributes

Tags: html, css, html-table

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-image: none;
}

.tableFull {
  table-layout: auto;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.mainRow1 {
  background-color: #7DD2CD;
  height: 10px;
}

.mainRow2 {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<table class="tableFull">
  <tr>
    <td class="mainRow1">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="mainRow2">
      test
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to create a table with a small first row and the rest of the page is supposed to be the rest of the page.

so like a 10 - 90 % distribution.

But when I create my table (that spans the whole page) the result is two rows that are 50 50, allthough I am cleary telling the first row to just be 10px in height (just to see what would happen) but that just gets totally ignored.

What is wrong?

[image]

Comment: What browser are you using? Looks okay on firefox and chrome desktop on Windows.

Comment: I am using firefox. But again: I dont want them to be the same height, i want the blue row to be just 10% and the gray one to be the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With empty cells, this will work, but if you have something in the cells, you can set it a height:

```html
<body>
    <table class="tableFull">
        <tr >
            <td class="mainRow1">
              <!--  -->
              <div style="height: 10px;">asd<br>asd</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td class="mainRow2">
                test
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

<style type="text/css">

    body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        background-image: none;
    }

    .tableFull{
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
    }

    .mainRow1{
        background-color: #7DD2CD;
        height:10px;
    }

    .mainRow2 {
        background-color: gray;
    }

 
</style>
```

Comment: unfortunately, this just leaves everything exactly as it was before. both rows are the same height

Comment: `table-layout` only affects column widths. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) for details.

Comment: Yes, I see that you have content in the first cell. Corrected the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use `max-height` instead of or aditionally to `height` on the class for the first-row cells:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-image: none;
}

.tableFull {
  table-layout: auto;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.mainRow1 {
  background-color: #7DD2CD;
  max-height: 10px;
}

.mainRow2 {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<table class="tableFull">
  <tr>
    <td class="mainRow1">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="mainRow2">
      test
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: still, the rows arew both 50 %...

Comment: not here, in the example above, viewed with Firefox

Answer (score 0):

I'm just dropping an answer on here as comments won't accommodate screenshots. With your code, this is what I'm seeing below. What version of firefox are you using? Also, does the [codepen](https://codepen.io/adamuk73/pen/abRvobx) link provided also give you a 50/50 split?

```
>
```

[image]

Comment: to my embaressment I had to say thatI had a global css file intervene with some of my layout and that is what caused the issue...

Comment: No worries. We've all been there.

Answer (score 0):

My original answer assumed you're creating a normal table for data but reviewing your post again, it looks like you're using `<table>` for a full page layout. I've revised this answer to use [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) to define a full page layout as an alternative.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-image: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tableFull {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  /* 'auto' sets the height of the first row to the height of its content.
    or use '10%' to set the height of the first row to 10% of the viewport.
    or '10px' for a specific height.
   '1fr' is used for the second row. Its height takes up the remaining space. */
  grid-template-rows: 10% 1fr;
}

.mainRow1 {
  background-color: #7DD2CD;
}

.mainRow2 {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="tableFull">
  <div class="mainRow1">
  </div>
  <div class="mainRow2">
    <span>test</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Additional CSS Grid [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids).